# Fetch refcursor into temporary table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, ref-cursor

I need fetch refcursor into temporary table. Each refcursor column should match appropriate table column + one key (enumerate) column should be in temp table. For example refcursor return  below data:

```
'one' 'Monday'
'two' 'Friday'
```

And the data which should store in table:

```
 1 'one' 'Monday'
 2 'two' 'Friday'
```

This refcursor is opened in other functions. So I does not know what columns should be in result set.
How I can implement something like FETCH ALL curs INTO temp_table ?

I wrote below function but it throws the error for (V_CURS_Rec).*

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_TEST() 
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql 
   AS $$ 
   DECLARE 
   V_CURS REFCURSOR; 
   V_CURS_Rec RECORD; 
   ITER INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
   create temporary table if not exists TMP_TBL 
   ( 
  INDX INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  CNAME VARCHAR(20), 
  CDAY VARCHAR(20), 
   ); 
   DELETE FROM TMP_TBL; 
  SELECT * FROM FN_RET_REFCURSOR() INTO V_CURS; 
  ITER := 1; 
   LOOP 
     FETCH V_CURS INTO V_CURS_Rec; 
     EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND; 
     INSERT INTO TMP_TBL SELECT ITER, (V_CURS_Rec).*; 
    ITER := ITER + 1; 
   END LOOP; 
  RETURN; 
END; $$;
```

Comment: Why do you even need the cursor? You could `INSERT INTO TMP_TBL  SELECT ...` directly, if I understand your code snipped right.

Comment: I already have the function with out refcursor parameter and i can't change this function. As I know I can't do INSERT INTO TMP_TBL SELECT ... for function with out refcursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a workaround I have done below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FN_TEST() 
RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE plpgsql 
   AS $$ 
   DECLARE 
   V_CURS REFCURSOR; 
   V_Rec_CNAME VARCHAR(20); 
   V_Rec_CDAY VARCHAR(20); 
   ITER INTEGER; 
BEGIN 
   create temporary table if not exists TMP_TBL 
   ( 
  INDX INTEGER NOT NULL, 
  CNAME VARCHAR(20), 
  CDAY VARCHAR(20)
   ); 
   DELETE FROM TMP_TBL; 
  SELECT * FROM FN_RET_REFCURSOR() INTO V_CURS; 
  ITER := 1; 
   LOOP 
     FETCH V_CURS INTO V_Rec_CNAME, V_Rec_CDAY; 
     EXIT WHEN NOT FOUND; 
     INSERT INTO TMP_TBL VALUES (ITER, V_Rec_CNAME, V_Rec_CDAY); 
     ITER := ITER + 1; 
   END LOOP; 
  RETURN; 
END; $$;
```