# Postgresql - Return column subset from cursor

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, database-cursor

I have a **legacy stored procedure** returning a number (row count) a cursor with many columns; I need to **retrieve a subset of the selected columns**. I can think of three ways of doing it:

1. Invoke the existing procedure **from the outside**, and map columns to my own data structures trimming unneeded columns;
2. Write a new stored procedure, **mostly identical to the existing one** but returning different columns;
3. Write a new stored procedure, **invoking the old one internally and filtering columns** (the referenced entities and thus the number of rows are exactly the same as the existing procedure).

Number 2 is obviously a no-go.

Number 1 is viable. As far as I know, there is little difference in the computing cost between retrieving one or more columns, in that the engine has to read full rows regardless, before filtering unrequired columns; I do have a feeling it would be **heavier on the runtime invoking the procedure from the outside**, as objects representing unneeded columns would exist on returning from the DB call.

I would be interested in **implementing Number 3**, but I would prefer to **maintain the same return type as the existing function** (count + **refcursor**) for conformity.

I think I could transfer all the rows in the cursor returned by the existing function into a **temporary table** as described e.g. [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50273139/fetch-refcursor-into-temporary-table), and use it as a **source for the output cursor** but:

- I am not sure of how the output cursor would behave with a temporary table created with a drop-on-commit clause (would the results exist reliably after the procedure has terminated? Would the temporary table be dropped as expected?);
- I read that temporary tables are expensive to use, and it feels like overkill for what in the end is a **filtering of columns on the same rows from a pre-computed result**.

Is there a way to **query the existing cursor** so that it may be used **as a source for the output cursor**, while **filtering columns**?

Comment: I think a temporary table might be your only option for solution 3.